# C++: Appending linked list recursively

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list

This code is supposed to append two linked lists, I totally fail to see how this code appends the two Cell Structs passed as arguments, as no manipulating is happening to the second parameter. it justs asks for the next node in the first Cell - so how can this work?

```
void Append(Cell *& first, Cell* second)
{
  if (first == NULL)
  {
    first = second;
  }
else {
    Append(first->next, second);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` block of the function keeps following the `next` pointer of `first` until it gets to the end of that list. That is, until `first->next` is `NULL` and the `else` does not get executed.

Now the base case in the `if` block. When `first->next` is `NULL`, it changes that pointer to point at `second`, which is presumably the first element in another list.

The reason there is some effect is because the `first->next` pointer is passed by reference. Modifying the pointer will modify the actual pointer at the end of the list, rather than just modifying a copy.

Answer (score 1):

It recurses until `first` is a reference to the `next` pointer of the last `Cell` in the first list, which it sets to point to the first `Cell` in the second. It doesn't need to manipulate `second` (assuming its a singly linked list).

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive algorithm that walks until the end of the first list (the `else` branch); once the end has been found (`first==NULL`), the first element of the second list is linked to the last element of the first one, obtaining a list that is the concatenation of the two original lists.

Answer (score 1):

The second list does not need to be modified. The code will recursively traverse the first list until it reaches the last element in the first list and set that element's next pointer to the start of the second list. The elements in the second list will be shared by both lists.

**before:**

```
first → a → b → c

second → d → e → f
```

**after:**

```
first → a → b → c
                ↓
second →        d → e → f
```